# Problem with css / js path is not opening in asp.net core blazor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor-server-side

I am shifting my development environment from windows to mac, and when I run the code after the complete setup, my website doesn't loads and doesn't shows any style and js doesn't work.

I have this path of the file, everything was working on my windows very fine but when I run it from the mac then the file path is not loading, how do I fix this? I am trying to search whole web, couldn't find this answer and ended up here :(

```
<link href="/_content/FileUploading.SearchEngine.Shared/content/styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="/_content/FileUploading.SearchEngine.Shared/content/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/_content/FileUploading.SearchEngine.Shared/content/styles/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/_content/FileUploading.SearchEngine.Shared/content/scripts/script.js" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image]

This become the url of the path of the file = https://localhost:5002/_content/FileUploading.SearchEngine.Shared/content/styles/dashboard.css

This doesn't loads.

Answer (score 0):

> I have this path of the file, everything was working on my windows
> very fine but when I run it from the mac then the file path is not
> loading, how do I fix this?

It would be nicer if you could share your configuration details regarding how you are calling the path and where is your actual resources are located. The issue you are having might be causing due to numerous reasons.

As you may know, a BlazorWebView control has a configured host file (HostPage), typically wwwroot/index.html. The HostPage path is relative to the project. All static web assets (scripts, CSS files, images, and other files) that are referenced from a [BlazorWebView are relative to its configured HostPage.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#static-assets-limited-to-razor-components)

Thus, web root of the HostPage determines which subset of static assets are available. Therefore, its recommended placing the HostPage at the root of the wwwroot folder of the app, which provides the greatest flexibility for supplying static assets from the app, RCLs, and via subfolders of the app and RCLs.

**How to Resolve:**

**Static File Middleware configuration :**

Let's consider, your resouce files are outside of your wwwroot folder; Therefore, In non-IIS hosting and reverse proxy hosting scenarios, additional Static File Middleware configuration might be required to serve static files correctly. For you scenario if your static are placed outside, please check if you are using as following:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "StaticFilesFolderName")),
    RequestPath = "/StaticFilesFolderName"
});
```

Then you should refer that files as following on your _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/StaticFilesFolderName/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

**Note:** Please [have a look this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root)

**Program.cs File:**

```
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
```

**Note:** If you have static file configuration you should have [UseStaticWebAssets in your program.cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#static-files-in-non-development-environments-for-blazor-server-apps) file just below the builder.

**Check App based path:**

As explained earlier, this might happening due to your resource path while moving to MAC. In this scenario its recommended to use relative based path reference on top of your base href in _Layout.cshtml after that you can place rest of your resource file. So if your resource are inside wwwroot place your [base href](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-base-path) top of your other path reference and access it by hostname/your_resource_path.

```
<base href="~/" />
```

and following should also work:

```
<base href="~/YourApp/" />
```

**Note:** The [trailing slash is required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac#app-base-path) in some scenrio if you would get any css loading issue.

**Static files in non-Development environments:**

Be aware of non development environment as well because  Blazor apps run locally, static web assets are only enabled by default in the Development environment therefore, to enable static files for environments other than Development during local development and testing we have to call [UseStaticWebAssets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#static-files-in-non-development-environments-for-blazor-server-apps) on the WebApplicationBuilder.

**Output:**

[image]